# How to create CommandBinding with a Parameter?

Tags: wpf, wpf-4.0

Is there a way to create a CommandBinding with a parameter?
You can normally add bindings to commands for controls doing something like this:

```
    <Control.CommandBindings>
          <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.XXX" CanExecute="XXX_CanExecute"
                    Executed="XXX_Executed">
          </CommandBinding>
    </Control.CommandBindings>
```

I was wondering if there was also a way to pass a paramater?

Comment: @NguyenKien I just think it is odd that you can not pass a paramater this way. I was wondering if maybe there was some special CommandBinding that supported Parameters, like instead of being called CommandBinding, it can be called CommandWithParametersBinding or something. Also why is that you cant pass parameters? Is there any particular reason?

Answer (score 0):

No, you dont have a `CommandParameter` on the `CommandBinding` but you can use the `InputBindings` from `UIElement` to add for example a `MouseBinding`, which has a `Command` and `CommandParameter` attribute.

```
<Control>
  <Control.InputBindings>
    <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftClick"
                  Command="{StaticResource MyCommand}"
                  CommandParameter="{x:Static system:Boolean.TrueString}"/>
    </Control.InputBindings>
</Control>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the parameter value to the `ICommandSource.CommandParameter` property of the element that invokes the command (for example `Button.CommandParameter`). This property also accepts a `Binding`.

You can retrieve the parameter from the `ExecutedRoutedEventArgs.Parameter` and `CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs.Parameter` property.

```xml
<Window>
  <Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Delete"                
                    CanExecute="DeleteCommand_CanExecute"
                    Executed="DeleteCommand_Executed" />
    </Control.CommandBindings>
  </Window.CommandBindings>

  <Button Content="X" 
          Command="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.Delete}"
          CommandParameter="abc" />
</Window>
```

```cs
private void DeleteCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var commandParameter = e.Parameter as string; // Returns "abc"
}

private void DeleteCommand_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var commandParameter = e.Parameter as string; // Returns "abc"
}
```

When clicking the `Button` or an `ICommandSource` in general, it sends the routed command along with the command parameter up the logical tree. The `CommandBinding` can catch this event and handle it using the registered handlers.
The point is that the command source must define the command parameter and not the `CommandBinding`. This way, the same `CommandBinding` can handle different command sources that send different command parameters.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried the [CommandParameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommandsource.commandparameter(v=vs.110).aspx) property?

```
<DataGrid.ContextMenu>
     <ContextMenu>
           <MenuItem Header="MyHeader" 
                     Command="{Binding MyCommand}"
                     CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItem}" />
</DataGrid.ContextMenu>
```

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't show for me, that is why I asked the question here, it seemed really odd that the property is not present. When I use it it tells me Cannot Resolve the Symbol "CommandParameter". Also that is under the Control, I am referring to use the CommandBinding tag.

Comment: @NguyenKien That's nonsense. CommandParameter works just fine.

Comment: There no CommandParameter in CommandBinding: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandbinding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @goobering doing it like Scott is you can, I am asking when you use the <CommandBinding Tag, not binding directly in the MenuItem, for instance.

Comment: Why don't you use the way Scott Nimrod suggest?

Comment: Because that wasn't the question he asked, probably. :-)